# How can I make my footer align to the very bottom?

Tags: html, css, alignment, footer

I'm new with CSS and have looked up many ways, but can't get the footer to align to the bottom. Any help? Thank you.

```
.footer {
    position: bottom;
    bottom: -10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #171717;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Change position to fixed.

```
.footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#171717;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also add the left property in case there are other divs and such that can push the footer

```
.footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 0px;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#171717;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like;

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #171717;
    color: white;
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/jghUs/)*** is a working Live Demo.

Answer (score 0):

### Demo on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/shahjehan/pen/pbEuB)

#### HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <h2>header</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2>container</h2>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h2>footer</h2>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  background: #f00;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  background: #ff0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-footer-group;
}
```